# c++ int is causing outputting max values

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm to solve a coding challenge in C++. However, I am having some trouble with large numbers. In cases with very large numbers this code produces the max signed int value.

Can someone just take a quick look at it and point out the flaw I cannot see?

This is the code:

```
int main()
{
    long long int n;
    long long int m;

    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;

    vector<pair<long long int, long long int>> adj[n];

    long long int tempA;
    long long int tempB;
    long long int tempC;

    for (long long int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> tempA;
        cin >> tempB;
        cin >> tempC;

        adj[tempA - 1].push_back({tempB - 1, tempC});
    }

    long long int distance[n];
    bool processed[n];

    fill_n(distance, n, INT_MAX);
    fill_n(processed, n, false);

    priority_queue<pair<long long int, long long int>> q;

    distance[0] = 0;
    q.push({0, 0});
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        long long int a = q.top().second;
        q.pop();
        if (processed[a])
            continue;
        processed[a] = true;
        for (auto u : adj[a])
        {
            long long int b = u.first, w = u.second;
            if (distance[a] + w < distance[b])
            {
                distance[b] = distance[a] + w;
                q.push({-distance[b], b});
            }
        }
    }

    for (long long i = 0; i < sizeof(distance) / sizeof(distance[0]); i++)
    {
        cout << distance[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

EDIT:

This was not working because of the properties of INT_MAX not scaling to 8 byte numbers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What input produces the error?

Comment: With very large `n` you overflow stack when declare 3 arrays. Note that variable size arrays are not allowed by standard c++.

Comment: `vector<pair<long long int, long long int>> adj[n];`  -- This looks like code from a so-called "geeks" website.  This is not valid C++.  You're already using vector, so you should be using it where it is meant to be used: `std::vector<std::vector<pair<long long int, long long int>>> adj(n);`.  The same thing with `bool processed[n]` and `long long distance[n];` -- these should be vectors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what is a "'geeks' website"

Comment: @M.Boyes -- If you go to "geeksforgeeks", their site has some good info on how to solve various problems, but the C++ implementations, for the most part, are very poor in terms of the language.  Using non-standard variable-length-array's and vectors in the same piece of code is one of their "specialties".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without *a clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers.  Have you tried to debug your code by running it step by step in a debugger?